# How to open new activity with onClickListener when an item is clicked in Firebase RecyclerView Cardview

Tags: android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, onclicklistener

I am using a **recyclerView** to show a list of receipts from **Firestore** which i have completed and can be seen here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuGQ4.png). Now i want to tap on the lists and be brought to a new activity that contains more detail about that receipt. i followed an online video and currently when you click on a list it shows the position of the item in firestore. I want to **click** on any receipt in the card view and be brought to a new activity that displays more details about that receipt. As you can see in my firebase and the list view, im only pulling 'store', 'total' and date from firestore but in this new activity you will see all the fields related to that receipt.

I have found similar post about this on stack but i still can't get it to work.

I have been at this for days so any help is greatly appreciated.

**ReceiptActivity.java**

```
public class ReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mFirestoreList;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private ReceiptAdapter adapter;
private CollectionReference receiptRef = db.collection( "users" )
        .document( "BtliRhtVFiQntlH2Hp1gvjG59b32" )
        .collection( "Receipts" );

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_receipt );

    mFirestoreList = findViewById(R.id.firestore_List);
    setUpRecyclerView();
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    Query query = receiptRef = db.collection( "users" )
            .document( "BtliRhtVFiQntlH2Hp1gvjG59b32" )
            .collection( "Receipts" );

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ReceiptsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ReceiptsModel>()
            .setQuery( query, ReceiptsModel.class )
            .build();

    //View holder class

    adapter = new ReceiptAdapter( options );
    mFirestoreList  = findViewById( R.id.firestore_List );
    mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize( true );
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );
    mFirestoreList.setAdapter( adapter );

    new ItemTouchHelper( new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            adapter.deleteItem( viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() );

        }
    } ).attachToRecyclerView( mFirestoreList );

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ReceiptAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            ReceiptsModel receiptsModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(ReceiptsModel.class);
            String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
            String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
            Toast.makeText(ReceiptActivity.this,
                    "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
}
```

**ReceiptAdapter.java**

```
public class ReceiptAdapter extends     FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ReceiptsModel, ReceiptAdapter.ReceiptHolder> {
private OnItemClickListener listener;


public ReceiptAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ReceiptsModel> options) {
    super( options );
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReceiptHolder holder, int i, @NonNull ReceiptsModel model) {
    holder.view_date.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.view_store.setText(model.getStore());
    holder.view_total.setText(String.valueOf(model.getTotal()));

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ReceiptHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    return new ReceiptHolder( v );
}

//delete receipt in the card view
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ).getReference().delete();
}

 class ReceiptHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView view_date;
    TextView view_total;
    TextView view_store;


    public ReceiptHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        view_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_date);
        view_store = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_store);
        view_total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_total);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick( getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ), position );
                }

                }
            });
        }
    }
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1** - Make small changes here in your ReceiptActivity

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ReceiptAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            ReceiptsModel model = documentSnapshot.toObject(ReceiptsModel.class);
            
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReceiptActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("date",model.getDate());
            intent.putExtra("email",model.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("store",model.getStore());
            intent.putExtra("total",model.getTotal());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Step 2**

Create DetailsActivity with 4 textviews in activity_details.xml (id of textviews date,email,store,total)

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView date,email,store,total;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        date = findViewById(R.id.date);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        store = findViewById(R.id.store);
        total = findViewById(R.id.total);
        date.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("date")+"");
        email.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("email")+"");
        store.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("store")+"");
        total.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("total")+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. are you saying you're not sure what im asking or you can't see the pictures properly?

Comment: Now, I have got it clearly. I will try to answer you very soon.

Comment: there's an issue in the DetailActivity. 'getIntent' is red so when i try to create a local variable 'getIntent' the app crashed.

Comment: Now it's okay. check it.